# VirtualBox vbox.log location in Linux?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

According to this [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/virtualbox-log-files-v2) from Oracle:

```
On Unix-like systems (Linux, Solaris), this is "$HOME/.VirtualBox/Machines/<vm name>/Logs"
```

However, there is no `.VirtualBox` inside my `$HOME` directory.

```
user@linux:~$ sudo find / -name vbox.log
user@linux:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That blog seems out of date.  I do not have `~/.VirtualBox` either.  There are other VirtualBox logs in `~/.config/VirtualBox` although not the `VBox.log` machine logs.

```
[user@Linux ~]$ ls ~/.config/VirtualBox/
compreg.dat                selectorwindow.log.10 selectorwindow.log.4  selectorwindow.log.7  vbox-ssl-cacertificate.crt  VBoxSVC.log.2  VBoxSVC.log.5  VirtualBox.xml
selectorwindow.log     selectorwindow.log.2   selectorwindow.log.5  selectorwindow.log.8  VBoxSVC.log                 VBoxSVC.log.3  VBoxSVC.log.6  VirtualBox.xml-prev
selectorwindow.log.1  selectorwindow.log.3   selectorwindow.log.6  selectorwindow.log.9  VBoxSVC.log.1               VBoxSVC.log.4  VBoxSVC.log.7  xpti.dat
[user@Linux ~]$
```

If you check the  [VirtualBox User Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#collect-debug-info) it says :

> Every time Oracle VM VirtualBox starts up a VM, a so-called release log file is created, containing lots of information about the VM configuration and runtime events. The log file is called VBox.log and resides in the VM log file folder. Typically this will be a directory as follows:
>
> $HOME/VirtualBox VMs/{machinename}/Logs

If you change the *Machine Folder* when creating a new VM they will be in a different place.  For example if you create a VM like this :

*Name* : **superuser**

*Machine Folder* : **/tmp/Temp**

After starting machine  you will find the `VBox.log` log(s) in `/tmp/Temp/superuser/Logs/`

```
[user@Linux ~]$ ls /tmp/Temp/superuser/Logs/
VBox.log  VBox.log.1  VBox.log.2
```

Comment: To get the VM log folder you may want to run `vboxmanage showvminfo <vm-name>` and grep for 'Log folder'.